# Вопрос по поводу циклов

Tags: c

нужен точный ответ. Цикл for и while. Какое утверждение правильное?

1. Вместо цикла for можно
   использовать цикл while без изменения
   алгоритма
2. Вместо цикла while можно
   использовать цикл for без изменения
   алгоритма

Comment: Что значит "без изменения алгоритма"?

Comment: Очевидно, второе. Всегда можно написать вместо `while (expr)` эквивалентный  `for (; expr;)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Цикл `for` - это набор собранный вместе команд для управления циклом. Для удобства записывания цикла. Здесь три команды для управления переменной `i`.

```
void f (void) {
  int s = 0 ;
  for (int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; ++ i )
    s += i ; }
```

То-же самое можно сделять использовав цикл `while`. Но управление переменной `i` будет разбросано по всей программе.

```
void w (void) {
  int s = 0 ;
  { int i = 0 ;
    while ( i < 10 ) {
      s += i ;
      ++ i ; } } }
```

Алгоритм у этих функций одинаковый. Ответ на первый вопрос : ДА. И на второй : ДА. Всё взаимозаменяемо.

---

На сладкое: вместо циклов `for` и `while` можно заменить на `if`.

```
void i (void) {
  int s = 0 ;
  { int i = 0 ;
again :
    if ( i < 10 ) {
      s += i ;
      ++ i ;
      goto again ; } } }
```

Все три цикла идентичны.

Comment: хочется как на braingames сказать «Неверно!» =)

Comment: В стандарте в дейстивельности приведено определение цикла for через цикл while, что удобнее для понимания что-же можно делать в заголовке цикла

Comment: если кратко, то представь, что во втором случае будет, если в теле цикла есть `continue`...

Comment: `continue;` - это сахар. идентичен команде `++ i ; goto again;` @Fat-Zer

Comment: а мы разве уже перестали сжигать на кострах тех кто использует `goto`?

Comment: А вот и не сожжёте. Я ассемблерист. @Fat-Zer

Comment: @AlexGlebe, по поводу `if`... , а слабО написать программу, в которой из управляющих инструкций  есть **только while**? Т.е. if, do ... while, for и goto отсутствуют.

Comment: @avp не надо кошмаров.. один студент писал код используя только switch  и битовые операции с магическими числами

Comment: @avp простые циклы то очевидно заменяются... `if`/`else` тоже несложно — условные переменные + циклы с обнулением этой переменной в конце тела... а вот с теми же `break`/`continue` под условиями скорей всего придётся код дублировать много-где...

Comment: @Fat-Zer почему? просто добавляется второй переход на инкрементируюшее выражение внутри "тела", break выходит из "тела" (при замене for() на while() break работают одинаково).

Comment: @Swift, потому что без `goto`...

Comment: @Fat-Zer может быть нерешаемым в некоторых случаях  в С++, в С возможно. Но это жесть, все управляющие операторы определены через if и goto. Крестовый поход Дийсктры против последнего был связан что в не было стандартов и четкого понимания что происходит при прыжке через операции или из блока. А еще есть ужасающая концепция "устройства Даффа"

Comment: @AlexGlebe напоминает использование `do { } while(0)` в макросах

Answer (score 2):

Как цикл `for()` определен через цикл с проверкой в начале (т.е. `while()`) в [(п 6.8.5)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2310.pdf)

```
for ( declaration expressionopt ; expressionopt ) statement
```

ИЗ ЧЕРНОВИКА С18 (п 6.8.5.3):

> ```
> for ( clause-1 ; expression-2 ; expression-3 ) statement
> ```
>
> behaves as follows: The expression expression-2 is the controlling
> expression that is evaluated before each execution of the loop body.
> The expression expression-3 is evaluated as a void expression after
> each execution of the loop body. If clause-1 is a declaration, the
> scope of any identifiers it declares is the remainder of the
> declaration and the entire loop, including the other two expressions;
> it is reached in the order of execution before the first evaluation of
> the controlling expression. If clause-1 is an expression, it is
> evaluated as a void expression before the first evaluation of the
> controlling expression.

(В С++ declaration назван init-statement, что правильнее отображает его роль как инструкции или определения.)

Следовательно определение из п 6.8.5 является эквивалентом и может быть заменено на

```
{
   declaration 
   while ( condition )
   {
      statement
      expression ;
   }
}
```

Такая замена не является "изменение алгоритма", т.к. поведение сохраняется буквально.

Очивидно, что `while ( condition )` можно заменить на `for(;condition;)`

Формально и (1) и (2) верны. (2) верен если условие читается "тело цикла остается неизменным"

особый случай представляет наличие `continue`. Если statement составной и содержит continue, то таковой является эквивалентом перехода на метку contin, расположенную после конца блока.

```
for (;;) {
{
// ...here was continue
}
contin: ;
}

while (foo) {
{
// ...here was continue
}
contin: ;
}
```

Comment: *"цикл for() определен через цикл while() в языке"* — в каком языке? В стандарте цэ не нашёл такого (https://docs.google.com/viewer?docex=1&url=https://web.archive.org/web/20181230041359if_/http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/abq/c17_updated_proposed_fdis.pdf)

Comment: @dlm0n может разница в версиях или черновиках? В С n1570 аж старое определение использовано , где первая часть названа выражением в синтаксисе (как в ооочень старом Си), но в тексте далее -  декларируещей инструкцией.

Comment: Так цэ и цэ++ разные языки, тут метка [tag:c] стоит, логично было бы ссылаться на его стандарт, а не на C++17

Comment: Да, логично, но все описано человеческим языком в тексте, один к одному. Все  черновики Си правда намеренно неполные. Даже в описании  как буд-то намеренно использованы другие имена.  Посмотреть-бы платную. Определение из С++ присутсвует в платной и бесплатной версии.